# XML code started with E, and contain lot of mess

Tags: xml

[image]

I had a work on some XML files, everything is fine except this one. This code on line 1 started with E and contain a lot of random text and symbols.

Comment: Did you configure your text editor to open it with a [Windows-1251 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)? (Why is anyone using Window-1251 this century anyway?!)

Comment: Yes, the result is still the same

Comment: That looks like a binary file. How did you receive that file? From where did you receive it? Are you sure it's not encoded in UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: It's from a game, i trying to make some mod :). Game is from Ukranian company GSC